# 'Where' clause in LINQ To XML not selecting anything

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am just trying to read some details from an XML file, part of which looks like this:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="applications.core.logging.CustomFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="C:\\Logs\\File.log"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
</appender>
<appender name="FILE" class="applications.core.logging.CustomFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="C:\\Logs\\File2.log"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="17"/>
</appender>
<appender name="FILE" class="applications.core.logging.CustomFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="C:\\Logs\\File3.log"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="98"/>
</appender>
```

I have several of these 'appender' nodes in my XML file. The following code loops through each 'appender' node. Within each 'appender' I want to pick out the param node with name "File" and check if the value is equal to what I am looking for.

```
foreach (XElement node in XmlFile.Descendants("appender"))
        {
            IEnumerable<XElement> elements = from el in node.Elements("param") 
                                             where el.Attribute("value").ToString().Equals("C:\\Logs\\File.log")) 
                                             select el;

            foreach (XElement el in elements)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found it " + el.Name);
                // Now read value for MaxBackupIndex
            }
        }
```

However my code is not printing anything out, so I think possibly the 'where' part of my LINQ query is incorrect, can anybody spot where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're calling `XAttribute.ToString()`. Try using `XAttribute.Value` instead, or just *cast* to a string. `ToString()` will return `value="C:\\Logs\\File.log"` - the name and the value - whereas you just want the value:

```
var elements = from el in node.Elements("param")
               where (string) el.Attribute("value") == "C:\\Logs\\File.log"
               select el;
```

Personally I wouldn't bother with a query expression here, btw:

```
var elements = node.Elements("param")
         .Where(el => (string) el.Attribute("value") == "C:\\Logs\\File.log")
```

EDIT: *Additionally*, as others have said, you want to have single backslashes in the XML file.

Comment: +1 ToString() was the main issue.  Also I would use a string literal @"C:\Logs\File.log" instead of escaping all the backslashes

Answer (score 8):

Attributes inside your XML file contains doubled slashes, but you are matching single ones. To match a double slash in an XML/TXT file, you need four slashes in your C# file.

Comment: This is a good point but not the answer unfortunately, still not matching when I make sure both are double.

Comment: @Jim: You need to combine both answers to get what you want, you have two mistakes

Comment: @Jim Jon Skeet has pointed out the other problem - I think you need a combination of answers to solve this.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I've edited my answer so it contains both. I'd totally missed it to start with.

Answer (score 4):

You are escaping your slashes in your where clause, but the XML already has double slashes - try adding an @ at the front of the strings in your where clause to escape the escaping (and take the string literally) and see if that helps:

e.g.

```
el.Attribute("value").ToString().Equals(@"C:\\Logs\\File.log"))
```

Comment: Pretty sure the XML is wrong in this case, not the parsing code (either way using `@` is a good idea for readability)

Comment: I can see where you are coming from - but the OP didn't say they had created the file so I made the assumption that they wanted to take the XML as is :)